# Why is there an option to declare a Swift Package's product dynamic or static?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

In a Swift package's manifest you declare products. For those products you can define their `types`. One option is `static`, another is `dynamic`, or you could leave it blank and the Swift Package Manager will automatically choose the type based on the client's preferences.

Why would I choose to make a vended library static over dynamic, or vice versa?

And how does that decision affect the consumer of the library if they are an iOS project?

Comment: Check out this [article](https://medium.com/@zippicoder/libraries-frameworks-swift-packages-whats-the-difference-764f371444cd)

Comment: @aheze Yea, I still don't get it. It says dynamic libraries cannot be used, except for the system libraries. Then it says frameworks are able to be used, but that they themselves encapsulate dynamic libraries. If dynamic libraries aren't allowed, then how come they are in frameworks? It doesn't answer why you would choose to include a `static` product in a swift package over a `dynamic` one, or vice versa. And it doesn't answer how those decisions impact the consumer of your library in the context of an iOS project.